# How can I use the Oracle `user` and `sysdate` functions in a Liquibase insert change set?

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I have a `changeSet` that looks similar to the one below:

```
<changeSet author="cwilliams" id="xxx">
    <insert tableName="SOME_TABLE">
        <!-- ... -->
        <column name="CREATED_BY_USER_NAME" value="user"/>
        <column name="CREATED_DT" valueDate="SYSDATE"/>
        <!-- ... -->
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

I'd like to set these two columns to the database user name and the current time, respectively. I put `user` and `sysdate` in as examples but I assume `user` would try to insert a user name of `user` and that's not what I want.

Is there a way to tell Liquibase to use the underlying database's functions for these values in a database agnostic way and, if not, is there a way to use specific Oracle functions for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`valueComputed`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html) attribute:

```
<changeSet author="cwilliams" id="xxx">
    <insert tableName="SOME_TABLE">
        <!-- ... -->
        <column name="CREATED_BY_USER_NAME" valueComputed="user"/>
        <column name="CREATED_DT" valueComputed="SYSDATE"/>
        <!-- ... -->
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

---

Another option would be, to define a default value when creating the table for those columns, then leave them out in the insert completely.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know, I don't use Liquibase.

However, if you have access to that schema, you could create a `BEFORE INSERT` database trigger, e.g.

```
create or replace trigger trg_bi_sometab
  before insert on some_table
  for each row
begin
  :new.created_by_user_name := user;
  :new.created_dt := sysdate;
end trg_bi_sometab;
/
```

On each insert, it would populate those columns with appropriate values.